# Returning a string from static function

Tags: c++

I have two files: DateTime.h and DateTime.cpp which are shown below:

DateTime.h

```
class DateTime
{
public:
    static string getCurrentTimeStamp();
};
```

DateTime.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DateTime.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string DateTime::getCurrentTimeStamp()
{
    return "";
}
```

My compiler (Visual Studio 2012) is spitting out errors the moment I have the function `getCurrentTimeStamp()` return an `std::string` object. The errors all point to syntactic problems but none are clear. Does anyone understand why this may be the case?

Update: Here are (some of) the errors.

> Error 6   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0
>   arguments c:\users\anthony\documents\code\consoleapplication1\datetime.cpp    21  1   ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'getCurrentTimeStamp' c:\users\anthony\documents\code\consoleapplication1\datetime.h  5   1   ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'getCurrentTimeStamp' c:\users\anthony\documents\code\consoleapplication1\datetime.h  5   1   ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 5   error C2371: 'DateTime::getCurrentTimeStamp' : redefinition;
>   different basic
>   types c:\users\anthony\documents\code\consoleapplication1\datetime.cpp    10  1   ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Missing #include <string>

Comment: You simply use `#include <string>` and  `std::string`  as required?

Comment: It might help if you told us what the errors are?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mascoj That does not appear to fix the issue.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I included a number of the errors, the only other thing I could do is upload the project.

Comment: @AppreciateIt Please don't. Take the time to make an actual MCVE instead. The link in my previous comment provides help with that.

Comment: There's more wrong with it, which is in the code you're not showing us

Comment: You need to include `string` before you include `DateTime.h`, otherwise `DateTime.h` is missing some critical definitions. And as @πάνταῥεῖ says you need to use `std::` in front of everything.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried that, the compiler is highlighting string fine without the std:: but I'll try that.

Comment: @deW1 I added the other only file in the project that I have touched aside from default configuration stuff that VS2012 adds.

Comment: I would put the `#include <string>` **in** the "DateTime.h" header, at the top.  And use std::string instead of just string.

Comment: I can't believe I got -3 for this question - I mean c'mon. Too harsh, I can assure you folks that the compiler is still not running this code.

Comment: @DanKorn Thank you, that fixed it. You can leave it as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: People will downvote if they think the question isn't complete. In this case it's hard to reconcile the errors with the code you've shown. I doubt though that anyone who has downvoted has bothered to actually compile this.

Comment: If you'd followed my suggestion of putting `#include <string>` *before* `#include "DateTime.h"` you'd find that @DanKorn 's suggestion is redundant. But that's a style choice more than anything else.

Comment: Do you mean in my DateTime.cpp? That was what I did, maybe there was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @AppreciateIt: kfsone's answer is basically the same as mine.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I prefer putting any #includes that the header needs in the header itself, so that source files don't have to add a bunch of other stuff just to use the header.

Comment: @DanKorn I usually do that too, but I'm sure I've seen arguments for the other style.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to diagnose an issue with a header file, especially a simple one like this, step 1 is to try and see what the compiler sees.

`#include` is a pre-processor directive, so the *compiler* doesn't see it, instead the compiler sees the pre-processed output of the file that you're trying to include.

So your code would look something like this:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

    //#include "DateTime.h"
    class DateTime
    {
    public:
        static string getCurrentTimeStamp();
    };
    //#include "DateTime.h"

    #include <ctime>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    string DateTime::getCurrentTimeStamp()
    {
        return "";
    }
```

http://rextester.com/MODV66772

When I try and compile this on RexTester's online Visual Studio, I get very different errors, telling me that your `stdafx.h` isn't empty.

If I modify the code a little:

```
    //#include "stdafx.h"

    //#include "DateTime.h"
    #include <string>

    class DateTime
    {
    public:
        static std::string getCurrentTimeStamp();
    };
    //#include "DateTime.h"

    #include <ctime>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    string DateTime::getCurrentTimeStamp()
    {
        return "";
    }
```

This now compiles without the errors/warnings you are reporting: http://rextester.com/PXE62490

The changes:

- include  in the header file, since the header depends on it,
- use `std::string` instead of `string`,

The C++ compiler is a single-pass compiler, so the header file can't know that you are intending to do `using namespace std` later, and even if it did, it's a terrible practice because the `std` namespace is densely populated.

If you absolutely can't do with typing `std::` all over the place, try `using` the names you need, e.g.

```
using std::string;  // string no-longer needs to be std::string
```

Comment: Maybe `DateTime.h` was included in `stdafx.h`?